# Excel Count number of times in range that cells in column A are less than corresponding cell in column B

Tags: excel, count, countif, sumifs

I have a range A2:B28. In column A, I have a bunch of numbers. In column B, I have a bunch of other numbers. I want to know how many times it occurs that a cell in column A is less than the cell on the same row but in column B (i.e. A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A28<B2:B28))
```